# Manual Advance to Specific Slide Without Pager in jQuery Cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slideshow, cycle

Is it possible to advance to a specific slide in jQuery cycle via a command rather than triggering a `click` on a pager?

Much like jQuery cycle offers the option to advance like so:

`$('#slideshow').cycle('next');`

I'd love to be able to pass a specific position somehow, so that I could advance to any slide programatically instead of on click.  Something like:

`$('#slideshow').cycle('advance(10)');`

Which would ideally let me navigate to the slide with an `eq` of 10. Anyone know of a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: what about [this example](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/goto.html)?

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  I should have dug a bit more in the docs.  Add it as an answer so I can give you credit :)

Comment: Marshall, can you answer this question with the example for others to see the solution easily. And thanks Marshall, spent hours looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using the same goto class. I also removed the pager attribute from the cycle.

My slide show id is s2. Code:

```
$('.goto').click(function() { 
    var rel = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
    $('#s2').cycle(rel); // you can also do (rel - 1) to follow the array
    return false; 
}); 

<div id="nav">
    <a href="#" class="goto" rel="0">Slider 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="goto" rel="1">Slider 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="goto" rel="2">Slider 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="goto" rel="3">Slider 4</a>
</div>
```